# Parsing Package & ROM problem

Tags: custom-roms, sony-xperia-arc-s

I have a bit of a mixed problem in my Xperia arc s. I started by trying to install apps, and I got that message saying "There was a problem parsing the package". I checked "unknown sources" in settings and made sure that I matched the minimum sdk required or higher and still the same message.

After that I tried to install a different rom, but whenever I flash a kernel I get stuck in CWM and the rom's zip file is not found! Even when I open the sd card from windows explorer it seems that the zip file has disappeared.

I used flashtool to get back to the original rom, but again whenever I try to install an app I face that "Parsing Package" problem again!

So what's wrong here? How can I get my phone working again so I can install apps?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a bad ROM install. You should try completely wiping the phone and re-installing the ROM from scratch. Make sure to clear the cache, the dalvik cache, and system. Then flash the original ROM back on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was with the sd-card, any new files weren't recognized on it so when i switched it with a new one the problem was solved though i can't format it till now